# PlayerGui.MainGui.TwitterCodeFrame.Enter.LocalScript:14: Expected 'end' (to close 'function' at line 1), got <eof>; (roblox studio)

Tags: lua, roblox

My code is:

```
script.Parent.Parent.Enter.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    local redeemEvent = game.ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("RedeemCode")

script.Parent.FocusLost:Connect(function(enter)
    if enter then
        redeemEvent:FireServer(script.Parent.Text)
    end
end)
redeemEvent.OnClientEvent:Connect(function(str)
    script.Parent.Text = str
    wait(3)
    script.Parent.Text = "Enter Code Here!"
end)
```

but it gives an error of:

> 15:53:44.277  Players.(my username).PlayerGui.MainGui.TwitterCodeFrame.Enter.LocalScript:14: Expected 'end' (to close 'function' at line 1), got ; did you forget to close 'function' at line 10?  -  Studio - LocalScript:14

Comment: Missing `end)` for the function starting on the first line of your snippet

Comment: sorry im kinda new where would i add the end)

Comment: @Braydon it is missing in line 3 to close the anonymous function definition that begins in line 1.